# Does Twig have a null coalesce operator?

Tags: twig, coalesce

I'm using the [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/) PHP template engine.

Is there an operator available which will output first non-empty value (coalesce)?

For example (using PHP pseudocode):

```
{{ title ?: "Default Title" }}
```

I know I could do something like this, but it's a bit long-winded:

```
{% if title %}{{ title }}{% else %}{{ "Default Title" }}{% endif %}
```

Comment: The answer is provided by @molecularman but I want to let you know you can make your last example shorter: `{{ title ? title : 'Default Title' }}`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, there is this filter called [default](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html). You can apply it to your code like below:

```
{{ title|default("Default Title") }}
```

Comment: This is incorrect, `default` performs a boolean-like evaluation, which e.g. means the non-null-value `false` will also be replaced with the default value. As of Twig v1.24 better use the `??` operator. See https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/empty.html

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, the link to the documentation that you shared is broken. Try this instead: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/default.html

Answer (score 64):

The null-coalescing operator was formally introduced in **Twig 1.24** (Jan. 25, 2016).

> [* adding support for the `??` operator](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/7e5c06a3be86f8321ea826ea80483dc5cfc9f081/CHANGELOG#L57)

Which means it's now possible to do this...

```
{{ title ?? "Default Title" }}
```

You can even chain them together, to check multiple variables until a valid non-null value is found.

```
{{ var1 ?? var2 ?? var3 ?? var4 }}
```

Answer (score 6):

As of Twig 1.12.0, it *does* have the `?:` operator, but it's not really "null coalescing". It checks for truthiness, not just nulls, thus `0 ?: 1` would come out `1`.

[Documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators)